# Minimizing IR Detection Interference

Tags: ir, remote-control

I'll start by saying that the goal here is to have a hand/distance detection device. Basically touch-less button.

I managed to get it working with a simple 2-pin IR emitter and 2-pin IR detector using analog read from the detector to trigger an event. The problem is that I get interference from the sun on bright days.

Is there a way to pulse the emitter at a specific frequency and have the detector activate only on that frequency and keep the 2-pin setup?

One solution I have been leaning towards is changing the IR detector to a IR decoder and basically treat it as a remote control but I can't see a way to detect distance using this method.

I am also open to any other ideas on getting something like this to work, without IR or ultrasonic.

Thanks.

Comment: search `VL6180X Time of Flight Distance Ranging Sensor`

Comment: Turn off the IR led. Read the value of the IR-detector. Turn **on** the IR led. Read the value of the IR-detector. The "subtract" the value without the led on, from the value with the led on. I put the word subtract in quotes, because I doubt it's that simple. You'd have to do some measurements, with different ambient light levels, and plot them in excel and see what their relation is. In short, calibrate your system. But maybe you need a different sensor to get a more accurate distance. Something like those ultrasonic sensors.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually something I have been meaning to try but never got around to it.

My idea is to drive the LED with PWM with a 50% duty cycle. The frequency isn't really that critical, but you don't want it too high for the next part.

Now you sample the receiver at a fixed frequency that is at least 2x the frequency of the PWM into a buffer.

Then you perform FFT on that buffer.

The bucket that contains the frequency of the PWM should have a power value that is proportional to the distance.

Other light sources will be unlikely to affect the same bucket as the PWM frequency - most will only affect the lowest (0Hz+) bucket.

Or that's the theory that I came up with. I have yet to try it in practice.